# Set up routing to access external router on the WAN interface

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have a network where I have a ISP supplied modem+router (192.168.50.1) that is connected to my main router (192.168.100.1). *I would like to connect to the ISP router through my main router.*

Today I can only do this via a direct connection in addition to a manual static ip configuration (192.168.50.100/255.255.255.0). That is a bit bothersome to do, as I have to crawl up on the attic to do so.

**The routing table on my main router**

```
default eth0 (WAN)  192.168.50.1    0
192.168.50.0/255.255.255.0  eth0 (WAN)  *   0
192.168.50.1    eth0 (WAN)  *   0
192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0 br-lan (LAN)    *   0
```

**The WAN details of my main router:**

```
WAN IP Address:192.168.50.100
WAN Netmask:255.255.255.0
WAN MAC Address:EC:08:6B:FF:D3:BD
WAN Gateway IP:192.168.50.1
WAN DNS Server(s):192.168.50.1
```

I know how to program stuff, but I never really learned the basics of routing which is probably why I cannot understand for the life of my why this routing table is not sufficient. To me it reads like this:

```
if someone is requesting traffic to 192.168.50.* on the LAN interface
then send it out on the WAN interface
```

And that is precisely what I am doing ... It does not seem to matter if I assign a manual IP (`192.168.50.100/255.255.255.0`) to the `.50` subnet, or just stay on the `.100` subnet. I still get

```
ping 192.168.1.50
PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
```

- My main router is running a DD-WRT mod called Gargoyle Router (v1.9).
- The main router (Gargoyle) is monitoring the bandwidth usage and throttling devices if they exceed their quota. This is needed due to many internal users and a limited quota from my ISP.
- I run OS X (and lots of other stuff), but just keep to the network basics: I know how to get around regardless of operating system :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't replace the ISP's router with yours, or is it one of those router/modem combos?

Comment: Guess I don't see how this could fail... The stock routing table that's automatically built by DD-WRT when the LAN is defined should handle this with no modification, you should not have to specify a route for this host or subnet as its outside your sunset, the default gateway will be used. What is the IP address, subnet, and gateway address of the Wan interface of your Gargoyle router?

Comment: So is your ISP router `192.168.1.50` or is it `192.168.50.1`? What subnets do you _actually_ have? What are the routing tables and interface configurations on _both_ routers? Does the 'inner' router perform NAT?

Comment: @Sane Yes, it's a router+modem combo (cellular internet).

Comment: What is the end goal? you could just plug it into one of the switch ports and call it good or with DD-WRT you can tell the WAN port to act like a standard switch port

Comment: Well, the main thing is that I need Gargoyle to monitor upload/download for all the clients, as I have a limited quota, and I need to control it. I was sure I needed to use the WAN port for the monitoring to work.

Comment: @acejavelin Added details to the question.

Comment: @grawity: thank you. you proved that I am a certified moron ... God damn it. I typed the wrong subnet.

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing for you do to... to access 192.168.50.1, you just go to it like normal... The standard routing table in the PC and router will handle it, your PC will pass the it to the gateway (your router) which will recognize it is on the subnet of the WAN interface and pass it directly to 192.168.50.1. If it doesn't work, your router isn't doing it's job, or the CPE router from your ISP is setup not to respond to anything outside of it's own subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a certified dummy. As @grawity pointed out, there is quite a big difference in typing 50.1 and 1.50 ...

Typing the right address makes quite a difference.

I typed 192.168.1.50, not 192.168.50.1, when trying to connect. Too many network changes in one day can do that to a person.